# Crop Cairo-Generated PDF

Tags: python, cairo

I have the following script which generates a number of circles in a box on top of a bigger circle. The output is to a PDF, which I would like to be tightly bounded to the ink extents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import math
import cairocffi as cairo
import random

def DrawFilledCircle(x,y,radius,rgba):
  ctx.set_source_rgba(*rgba)
  ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*math.pi)
  ctx.fill()

def DrawCircle(x,y,radius,rgba=(0,0,0,1)):
  ctx.set_source_rgba(*rgba)
  ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*math.pi)
  ctx.stroke()

surface       = cairo.RecordingSurface(cairo.CONTENT_COLOR_ALPHA, None)
ctx           = cairo.Context (surface)

DrawCircle(200,200,150,(0,0,0,1))
for i in range(1000):
  DrawFilledCircle(200+(150-300*random.random()), 200+(150-300*random.random()), 4, (0,0,0,0.5))

#This part will change throughout the question
extents = surface.ink_extents()
pdfout  = cairo.PDFSurface ("circle.pdf", extents[2], extents[3])
pdfctx  = cairo.Context (pdfout)
pdfctx.set_source_surface(surface,0,0)
```

Running the script produces the following.

[image: Circle cropped in bottom right]

As you can see, the width and height are correct, but the origin needs to be shifted. Accordingly, I tried this:

```
pdfout  = cairo.PDFSurface ("circle.pdf", extents[2], extents[3])
pdfctx  = cairo.Context (pdfout)
pdfctx.set_source_surface(surface,extents[0],extents[1])
```

This just shifted things further to the bottom right.

[image: Circle cropped even more in the bottom right]

That suggested using negative coordinates to shift things the other way:

```
pdfout  = cairo.PDFSurface ("circle.pdf", extents[2], extents[3])
pdfctx  = cairo.Context (pdfout)
pdfctx.set_source_surface(surface,-extents[0],-extents[1])
```

But that didn't work either:

[image: Negative coordinates didn't work]

As a back-up, I could make a shell call to `pdfcrop`, but that seems like a ridiculous workaround.

What can I do to achieve what I'm trying to do? Where am I going wrong? How can a lasting peace be achieved in Cairo?

Comment: What's wrong the the last version? Why are you saying it didn't work either?

Comment: @UliSchlachter, the cloud of gray circles should cover the entire bounding box of the larger circle. But they are somehow not appearing along the right and bottom sides, even though the larger circle is.